# Is it allowed to log location to remote server in iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, location

I have build a game about languages, that is soon going to be uploaded to Appstore. I have a function that sends the result to my server, to be able to see which questions that was too easy/hard. At the same time, since it is about languages, it would be interesting to see where the user come from. Am I allowed to collect location data for this? I think I read somewhere that it might offend the integrity.

Answer (score 2):

See the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), item 4.1. That implies that you should be ok if you ask the user for permission before gathering and transmitting the location data. It may even be sufficient to just properly set the [`purpose`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/purpose) on the CLLocationManager instance before starting location services.

Comment: It's not really relevant for the game itself, just for my analytics for improving the game. So I'm not sure about this: "Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the app to the user or to support approved advertising uses"